# Multi-room chat application with websockets and redis

Tags: go, websocket, redis, real-time

I want to create a chat application with multiple rooms.
I have Postgres database with tables: users, chats, chat_users, friends, friend_requests, chat_invites, messages. To notify users in realtime I use websockets which are stored in map and each one has it's own id (it's always id of user). To notify group of clients I store connection ids in redis sets and each time I need to send `event` to room I get members via `smembers` in []int64 and send to each one iterating through array. Is it a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, your approach seems somewhat over-engineered.

I'd start by creating the simplest possible thing that works - without using either Postgres or Redis. The server can keep its data in some maps/structs protected by a lock for concurrency. Clients don't need any of that anyway.

Once you have a basic working thing, you can start considering more involved architectures to answer specific needs.

This will help you bisect the problem to smaller and more manageable chunks.

Comment: I have already created chat, it works, but i am not sure if it's performance efficient

Comment: @LilYung: not sure how moving data to a DB will help you be *more* efficient

Comment: opening 30000 rooms on one server takes a lot of ram(if you use maps)

Comment: @LilYung: are you really planning this service for 30,000 rooms? Did you measure memory usage for Go's 30,000 map entries vs. Redis's 30,000 map entries? TBH 30,000 is not that much. At 10K per entry that's 300MiB of RAM - hardly a disaster. If you're building a real production service I'd be more worried about fault tolerance, but that's a completely different topic